# SELinux blocking Samba access to mounted volume despite samba_share_t

Tags: samba, selinux, centos8

I repurposed an old AMD A10 APU-based machine that was collecting dust in my basement to act as a NAS, and eventually some other light-duty tech work. It's running CentOS 8.1, the boot disk is a 340GB hard drive I had laying around, and I have a 2TB, 2-drive RAID-1 array I put together with `mdadm` intended to be used mainly for the NAS. The RAID array (`/dev/md0`) is mounted to `/media/raid0` and inside is a directory called `nas` set to mode 777. I have this line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/md0    /media/raid0    ext4    defaults    0    0
```

Samba is set to share `/media/raid0/nas` as a share called "fileshare". Following the [SELinux recipe for Samba](https://selinuxproject.org/page/SambaRecipes), I applied the `samba_share_t` label recursively to `/media/raid0/nas` and made it permanent with the `semanage` command.

However, when I attempt to browse `\\SERVER\fileshare` on a Windows machine, it says it can't connect. When I try to access it with `smbclient` on the server, I get kicked out with `NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME`. Samba's logs show repeated errors saying `canonicalize_connect_path failed for service fileshare, path /media/raid0/nas`.

BUT, If I disable SELinux with `setenforce 0`, the share suddenly works like flipping a switch. No errors, I connect with no problems.

To recap:

- `/media/raid0/nas` is the path being shared as `fileshare`
- `/media/raid0/nas` is extremely permissive (mode 777)
- I have applied the `samba_share_t` label to `/media/raid0/nas` and it's set to be done recursively in SELinux
- I can connect to the share without issue if SELinux is disabled (`setenforce 0`).

Why is SELinux still blocking this share? I'll note that I also tried moving the mountpoint to `/raid0` but got the same results.

Edit: I'm seeing entries like this in my audit logs:

```
time->Mon Nov  2 22:41:39 2020
type=AVC msg=audit(1604374899.147:1102): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=8091 
comm="smbd" name="/" dev="md0" ino=2 scontext=system_u:system_r:smbd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
```

Comment: Check the audit log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I turned SELinux back on, ran `tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log` and it doesn't add any entries to the log when I try to access the share.

Comment: If it's happened before, then there ought to be audit log entries already. In any case, if the problem happens when the client is trying to connect, then that's what you need to attempt.

Comment: Added a relevant audit log entry to my post.

Comment: What filesystem did you use for `/media/raid0/nas`? And what are the mount options you set in `/etc/fstab` for it?

Comment: Added my fstab entry to the post - it's an ext4 filesystem with default options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audit log entry says your mount point `/media/raid0` doesn't have an SELinux label. Nevermind the `nas` directory, it can't get that far!

You'll need to set an appropriate SELinux context for `/media/raid0`. Restoring the default context `mnt_t` should be sufficient.

```
restorecon -v /media/raid0
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like it tries to descend starting from the root, inode=2, dir name=/. Means you either need to adjust the permissions accordingly from the top or put samba into a chroot-like namespace environment where same restrictions are to be  loosen.

Comment: (written on smartphone)